# Unit Test The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, moq

I am writing a webAPI unittest that have several test call for each method in the class. I am using UseInMemoryDatabase to create a database and loading test data.

I was getting the following error between each test method

The instance of entity type 'AppSettings' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'myId '} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

I added context.Database.EnsureDeleted(); and that removed the error for the Get method but it was still throwing the error in the delete and update unit test.

I can't figure how to removed this error for delete and update when I run all the test methods at once.

Any help is appreciated.

```
        private MyDBContext context;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
            {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDBContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "MyDB")
                .Options;

            context = new CACIDBContext(options);
 
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();  // this removed the error between the several GET test methods. but not the delete,update
            context.AppSettings.Add(new AppSettings { myId = 1, MyName = "test1", MyValue = "test1" });
            context.AppSettings.Add(new AppSettings { myId = 2, MyName = "test2", MyValue = "test2" });
            context.AppSettings.Add(new AppSettings { myId = 3, MyName = "test3", MyValue = "test3" });

            context.SaveChanges();
             
        }

[TestMethod]
        public void GetSettings()
        {
            var logger = new Mock<ILogger<SettingsRepository>>();
            var caciDbContent = new Mock<CACIDBContext>();
            sRepository settingRepository = null;

            settingRepository = new sRepository (context, logger.Object);
            List<AppSettings> settings = settingRepository.GetSettings().ToList();
            Assert.AreEqual(3, settings.Count);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void RemoveSetting()
        {
            var logger = new Mock<ILogger<sRepository>>();
            var caciDbContent = new Mock<CACIDBContext>();
            sRepository sRepository = null;
 

            sRepository = new sRepository (context, logger.Object);
                // test Get By AppSettingName
                bool result = sRepository.RemoveSetting(new AppSettings { myId  = 3, MyName = "test3", MyValue = "test3");
                Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
 
        }



Here is my c# code

        public bool RemoveSetting(AppSettings setting)
        {
            try
            {
                myDbContent.AppSettings.Remove(setting);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError($"Failed to removfe an existing appsetting: {ex}");
                throw ex;
            }

            return (myDbContent.SaveChanges() > 0 ? true : false);
        }
```

Comment: I've had this before and resorted to creating the context for each test. I think it was something to do with the change tracker or a domain object persisting between tests. I'm assuming with the usage of .EnsureDeleted() you've tried EfCore.TestSupport? There are a few options at hand covered in the doco https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCore.TestSupport/wiki/5.-Quickly-create-empty-database which may help.

Answer (score 6):

Adding the following line helped in my case, which is similar to yours.

```
context.ChangeTracker.Clear()
```

It is only available for EF Core 5.0 though. Source: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.clear?view=efcore-5.0)